# Ununderstandable Processing behavior

Tags: processing

I just can't understand this trivial script's behavior in Processing.

For a ParticleSystem of size 1, it works. As soon as the size is over 1, the Particles go crazy. Why?

Sketch to run :

```
float dt = 1;
ParticleSystem ps;

void setup(){
  size(700,700);

  // PARTICLE SYSTEM
  PVector origin = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
  ps = new ParticleSystem(12, origin); // Change the number here to see the weird behavior !
}

void draw(){
  background(255);

  // PARTICLE SYSTEM
  ps.run();
}
```

Particle Class :

```
class Particle {

    private PVector pos;
    private PVector prevPos;
    private PVector vel;
    private PVector force;

    private float m = 10;
    private float r = 60;
    private boolean dead = false;

    Particle(PVector pos, PVector vel) {
        this.prevPos = pos;
        this.vel = vel;
        this.force = new PVector(0, 0);
        this.pos = new PVector();
        this.pos.x = pos.x + vel.x * dt + 0.5 * force.x / m * sq(dt);
        this.pos.y = pos.y + vel.y * dt + 0.5 * force.y / m * sq(dt);
    }

    void display() {
        color c = color(0);
        fill(c);
        ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
    }

    void run() {
        this.update();
        this.display();
    }

    void update() {
        this.moveVerlet();
    }

    void moveVerlet() {
        PVector tempPos = new PVector(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        this.pos.x = this.pos.x * 2 - this.prevPos.x + sq(dt) * this.force.x / this.m;
        this.pos.y = this.pos.y * 2 - this.prevPos.y + sq(dt) * this.force.y / this.m;
        this.prevPos.set(tempPos);
    }

}
```

Particle System Class :

```
 class ParticleSystem {

    private ArrayList<Particle> particles;
    private PVector origin;

    ParticleSystem(int nb, PVector origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.particles = new ArrayList<Particle>(nb);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nb ; i++) {
            float k = 0.5;
            float vx = random(-k, k);
            float vy = random(-k, k);
            this.particles.add(new Particle(origin, new PVector(vx, vy)));
        }
    }

    void checkBoundaries() {
        for (int i = this.particles.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            if (this.particles.get(i).pos.x - this.particles.get(i).r <= 0
                || this.particles.get(i).pos.x + this.particles.get(i).r >= width) {
                this.particles.get(i).prevPos.x = this.particles.get(i).pos.x + this.particles.get(i).pos.x
                    - this.particles.get(i).prevPos.x;
            }
            else if (this.particles.get(i).pos.y - this.particles.get(i).r <= 0
                || this.particles.get(i).pos.y + this.particles.get(i).r >= height) {
                this.particles.get(i).prevPos.y = this.particles.get(i).pos.y + this.particles.get(i).pos.y
                    - this.particles.get(i).prevPos.y;
            }
        }
    }

    void run() {
        checkBoundaries();
        for (Particle p : this.particles) {
            p.run();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please narrow down your question

Comment: I have no idea where the probleme comes from. Only that it must be in the Particle class, I guess in the moveVerlet() method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you pass the `origin` into the `ParticleSystem` constructor. You then pass that into the `Particle` constructor, and the `Particle` class stores that in the `prevPos` variable, which it uses for updating the position of each `Particle`.

So you've got multiple instances of `Particle` sharing the same `prevPos` variable. Uh oh!

The problem is that the `Particle` class also **modifies** that `prevPos` variable. So now you've got multiple instances of `Particle` all modifying that same `prevPos` variable, which you then use to update the position, and you start accumulating errors.

The solution is to just **copy** the `origin` `PVector` before passing it into each `Particle` constructor. Luckily `PVector` has a `copy()` function that does exactly that:

```
this.particles.add(new Particle(origin.copy(), new PVector(vx, vy)));
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/PVector_copy_.html).